# Hessian using finite difference approach in Python

Tags: python, numerical-methods, differentiation

Lets say, I have a function `z = x^2 + y^2`. Now, I want to implement hessian of this function `z` in python. Till now, I have calculated the derivative using finite-difference method as given below -

```
def derivative(x, y, f, h):
    return [(f(x + h, y) - f(x - h, y )) / (2*h), (f(x , y + h) - f(x , y - h)) / (2*h)]
```

I'm not sure how to reuse this to calculate the Hessian.

Comment: For the diagonal terms you can use the second order finite difference `f_xx = (f(x+h) - 2*f(x) + f(x-h))/(h^2)`.  For the off diagonal terms you can derive the expression by the `x` derivative followed by the `y` derivative.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler method: use the `numdifftools` package. It has the `Hessian` function, which does what you want. [Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/numdifftools/)

Comment: I would like to write it from scratch.